# Why my jQuery and updatepanel is not working after postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function autoComp() {
            $('[id*="tipcombo"]').selectToAutocomplete();
            $('[id*="aractipi"]').selectToAutocomplete();
            $('[id*="bulundugu"]').selectToAutocomplete();
        });
    });

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $('[id*="tipcombo"]').selectToAutocomplete();
            $('[id*="aractipi"]').selectToAutocomplete();
            $('[id*="bulundugu"]').selectToAutocomplete();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I use that code to prevent from postback but it's not working. I also tried Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() method and it's again not working.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   autoComp();
});
```

Now I just wrote simple function in codebehind, and every postback event it's bind it again with stringbuilder append. But this is not a healty solution.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors ? - do you step throw this javascript code to see if they actually called ?

Comment: No I did not get any error. I also debug it and it's entering that event and it seems give that code but still not working. Very interesting situation.

Comment: Try to comment out `$(document).ready` code and use `pageLoad` function only without partial postback check. BTW you didn't define the `autoComp` function but use it as nested `document.ready` handler. Also if `tipcombo`, `aractipi` and `bulundugu` are server controls, better use this selector syntax: `$("#<%= tipcombo.ClientID %>, #<%= aractipi.ClientID %>, #<%= bulundugu.ClientID %>")`

Comment: Unfourtunately same result ...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UXn64UjZ   After repeater radiobutton checkedchanged jquery code is gone.

Answer (score 0):

jquery and asp.net ajax library Conflict.
to Eliminate Conflict:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('[id*="tipcombo"]').selectToAutocomplete();
        $('[id*="aractipi"]').selectToAutocomplete();
        $('[id*="bulundugu"]').selectToAutocomplete();
});
</script>
```

or [visit this](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)